# C# Windows Form - How do I assign a double value to a combo box string to then be displayed in a text box?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, combobox, textbox

I've been having the trouble of finding a solution to my coding problem of assigning a double value to a combo box item which then that double value is displayed and added to a text box.

For instance, the beverages combo box contains: soda, tea, coffee, milk, juice, etc. So for "soda" I would like to give it the value of $1.95 which is then displayed in a "Subtotal:" text box. So then for every time a item is selected in the combo box, say soda, juice, and coffee, every time a item is selected it would add to the previous subtotal value in the text box.

Sorry if it isn't too clear but any help would be great, I've blanked out and been trying to come up with a solution for a while now and just been struggling. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome!  Can you show us what you have been attempting for _"coding problem of assigning a double value to a combo box item"_ please?  This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This would be a perfect use of a custom type. In this case you could create a Drink class with a Description property and a Price property. Override the .ToString() method to display only the Description.

```
class Drink
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Description;
    }
}
```

From that you would instantiate a new Drink, populate the Description and the Price and add that object to your combobox. Your combobox would display "Soda" but the object also holds 1.95 in its Price property.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //for demonstration purposes, we're creating 3 Drink
    //objects and adding them to the combobox. Normally
    //you would loop through a data source of some sort
    //and populate your combobox with the newly intantiated objects.
    Drink item;

    item = new Drink();
    item.Description = "Soda";
    item.Price = 1.80M;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

    item = new Drink();
    item.Description = "Coffee";
    item.Price = .95M;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

    item = new Drink();
    item.Description = "Tea";
    item.Price = .65M;
    comboBox1.Items.Add(item);

}
```

Since the combobox is holding an object, you would need to cast the selecteditem back to a Drink so that you have access to the price from the selection.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal itemPrice;
    //if the textbox is empty or cannot be parsed to a decimal
    //then we cast the combobox1.SelectedItem to a Drink type
    //place that value into the textbox. If, however, it can be
    //parsed to a decimal then we grab that value and add the
    //price of our newly selected combobox item to the price
    //that is currently in the textbox.
    if(decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out itemPrice))
    {
        textBox1.Text = (itemPrice + ((Drink)(comboBox1.SelectedItem)).Price).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1.Text = (((Drink)(comboBox1.SelectedItem)).Price).ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a good solution and one that I would use in this situation... it may be a bit much for a (presumably) new programmer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (please provide what you have already tried next time, it makes it easier for us to help.) you can use a dictionary to map your beverages to a price.

```
var priceMapping = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
    { "Soda", 1.75 },
    { "Tea", 2.00 },
    { "Coffee", 1.50 }
    //etc...
};
```

And then, on the selected index changed event for the combobox, you can do something like this:

```
ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
if (comboBox != null && comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
{
    //For simplicity sake, I left error handling
    //You'll want to use double.TryParse to handle any unexpected text in the subtotal textbox.
    double price = Convert.ToDouble(subTotalTb.Text) + priceMapping[comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()];
    subTotalTb.Text = price.ToString();
}
```